# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Populate drop down list from a Dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to poplulate a drop down list in MVC 2 from a Dictionary{string, string}.
My code below, that is not quite right...

states is the Dictionary. Help

```
<tr>
<td class="formtext">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.State)%> <strong>*</strong>
</td>
<td align="left">
    <%= Html.DropDownList("statesDropDown", null, null, new { @class = "ddlAttributeGroups" })%>
</td>
</tr>
```

ActionResult:

```
var states = new States().GetStates();
var statesDropDown = new SelectList(states, states.Keys.ToString(), states.Values.ToString());
ViewData["statesDropDown"] = statesDropDown;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using ViewData instead of view models and strongly typed views which would make your code much more clear/safer/Intellisense enabled, ...? Why are you using dictionaries instead of some simpler types? Like for example a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedState { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var states = new States().GetStates();
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        States = states.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Key,
            Text = x.Value
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and a strongly typed view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    x => x.SelectedState, 
    new SelectList(Model.States, "Value", "Text"), 
    null, 
    new { @class = "ddlAttributeGroups" }
) %>
```

See how easy it is?

Comment: I like this a lot, but what would you suggest to use instead of the dictionary of States?  private Dictionary<string, string> StatesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "AL", "Alabama" },
            { "AK", "Alaska" },
            { "AZ", "Arizona" }, ...

Comment: @Mark, I would suggest you an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` on your view model and an `IEnumerable<SomeModelType>` on your domain model.

Comment: The x => x.SelectedState part doesn't work, it says, "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"